# Firebase Storage Video Decoder

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, hevc

I want to save a video in the firebase storage and play that video in an application. My current structure is: 
**FOR SAVE**
    `Save mp4 video>in firebase storage>get url`

**FOR PLAY**
    `get mp4 video by url<from firebase storage`

But I think this will generate broadcast. So I want the next structure, because I think this should help me:

**FOR SAVE**
`Save mp4 video>in firebase storage>coding video>get url`

**FOR PLAY**
`get video HEVC by url<transcoding<from Firebase Storage`

I don't know how to do it.
I think I need to use Google Cloud Platform but I dont know how?

My project is a video on demand app.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to communicate by saying things like `Save mp4 video>in firebase storage>get url`.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

better use Cloud Storage instead of Firebase; at least for the storage.

while the transcoding probably should already happen on upload.

for reference: [Use Case](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/architecture/transcoding/).

Comment: Cloud Storage is the same as Cloud Storage for Firebase, except the Firebase adds SDKs for use in mobile apps that access Cloud Storage directly.